# can we detect eye without face detection in open cv

Tags: android, opencv, eye-detection

I am working on opencv in android. can anyone tell that can i detect eye without face detection? my code is:

```
    Rect e = eyesArray[i];
        e.x = area.x + e.x;
        e.y = area.y + e.y;
        Rect eye_only_rectangle = new Rect((int)e.tl().x,(int)( e.tl().y + e.height*0.4),(int)e.width,(int)(e.height*0.6));
        mROI = mGray.submat(eye_only_rectangle);
        Mat vyrez = mRgba.submat(eye_only_rectangle);
        Core.MinMaxLocResult mmG = Core.minMaxLoc(mROI);

        Core.circle(vyrez, mmG.minLoc,2, new Scalar(255, 255, 255, 255),2);
        iris.x = mmG.minLoc.x + eye_only_rectangle.x;
        iris.y = mmG.minLoc.y + eye_only_rectangle.y;
        eye_template = new Rect((int)iris.x-size/2,(int)iris.y-size/2 ,size,size);
        Core.rectangle(mRgba,eye_template.tl(),eye_template.br(),new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 2);
        template = (mGray.submat(eye_template)).clone();
        return template;
    }
     return template;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try haar cascade classifier with the xml for "eyes":
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades

If you're also willing to consider other packages, you can try STASM or flandmark detector.

Comment: i found no haar cascade classifier with xml for eyes. kindly if u share that xml ?

Comment: I added a link where you can download the xml.

Comment: can we have haar cascade for eye balls ?

Comment: What do you mean? I linked to the haar cascade for eyes.